# Why doesn't string.Formatter.format have a "self" parameter?

Tags: python, string, class, self

When reading the source code of the `string` module of python, I am confused by the class `Formatter`.

The `format` method (not static nor class method) in the Formatter class does NOT have `self` as input parameter `def format(*args, **kwargs):`, but somehow use it directly within the method. `self, *args = args`.

Please explain this usage.

```
class Formatter:
    def format(*args, **kwargs):
        if not args:
            raise TypeError("descriptor 'format' of 'Formatter' object "
                            "needs an argument")
        self, *args = args  # allow the "self" keyword be passed
        try:
            format_string, *args = args # allow the "format_string" keyword be passed
        except ValueError:
            if 'format_string' in kwargs:
                ...
            else:
                ...
        return self.vformat(format_string, args, kwargs)
```

Comment: `self` is **not** a keyword, it's a name used by convention: https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

Comment: @UnholySheep, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self` is assumed to be the first `arg` in `*args`, and unpacked in this line:

`self, *args = args`

Declaring an instance method without self in the signature is unusual in Python.

By looking at the [git history](https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/be1eb1424121682081fed8996e87e2dfd238e7ea/Lib/string.py#L163) for the method signature line we can see that originally `self` was present.

It was removed because its presence caused an error if the format string contained a variable named `self`, for example `'I am my{self}'`.  The unusual pattern of unpacking `self` from `args` was introduced to fix the bug.

The bug report and discussion is [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue23671).

This is an example of the error, from the bug report:

```
>>> string.Formatter().format('the self is {self}', self='bozo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: format() got multiple values for argument 'self'
```

Comment: That answers the what... but why? The `self` reference is always the first param passed into a class method so why go to the trouble of using tuple unpacking inside of the method to split off self from the positional args when you could have just made a parameter for it?

Comment: @snakecharmerb, thanks. Good technique by looking into git history.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are familiar with the `*args` syntax in the argument. This is just an arbitrary list of unnamed arguments. Then you have

```
self, *args = args  # allow the "self" keyword be passed
```

That comment is pretty explicit. Your are splitting `args`, which is a list, into a first element (which we usually call `self`, but is just a regular argument, always the first one in an object method), and the rest. Thus, we read `self`, and all is well - not immediately, but in the function.

The only use case I can see here is from

```
if not args:
        raise TypeError("descriptor 'format' of 'Formatter' object "
                        "needs an argument")
```

This means we are expecting to do stuff like

```
Formatter.format(formatterObj,format_string,...)
```

a lot (not sure why, something like a factory?), so in case we forget to send the `self` - `formatterObj` in my example, we get a verbose error. Possibly to support `Formatter` like objects that do not have a `format` method, but do have a `vformat` method. Seems rather unlikely though.